# How to access the objects inside another objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the nested object named data. Here I want to display all the objects keys and values. For that I have written a code which is below:

```
var data = {
       response: {
           deals: [
                    {
                    id: 1,
                    color: {
                          id: 608290
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
          };
```

Using below code I have reached to access object deal's "id" that is key and its value that is 1 but gives [object object ] for color, because it has its own key and value i.e id:608290. I want to display it too. Please make some change to code to get that key and value too of color object inside of deals.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= data.response.deals.length-1;i++){
    $.each( meta.response.deals[i], function( key, value ) {
        alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

Comment: Is `meta.response.deals` an array?

Comment: Yes: `deals: [ { id: 1, color: { id: 608290 } } ]`. It's an array of objects.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Is your Object graph `metal.deals` or `meta.response.deals`?

Comment: @Uchenna thnx ,can u pls have a look once again i have made corrections

Comment: @Uchenna i want to use each function again to get the key and the value inside each function alrdy written .Is it possible?

Comment: @king You don't need `$.each` again. You have objects in `deals` array. So the first `$.each` or `for loop` loops through all the objects you have in the `deals` array. All you need is to use `.` to get the properties of each object. I hope this make sense now. Check my answer

Comment: @king: If one of the answers helped you solve your problem, please mark it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will run through the object's array. Withing the loop you can do whatever you want to do with the deals.

```
var data = {
    response: {
        deals: [{
            id: 1,
            color: { id: 608290 }
        },
        {   id: 2,
            color: { id: 123456 }
        },
        {   id: 9001,
            color: { id: 456789 }
        }]
    }
};

for (var i in data.response.deals) {
    var obj = data.response.deals[i];
    console.log(obj);

    // obj.id       => current ID
    // obj.color.id => color's ID
}
```

Log:

```
{"color": {"id": 608290}, "id": 1}
{"color": {"id": 123456}, "id": 2}
{"color": {"id": 456789}, "id": 9001}
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/ipeful/4

Comment: Broxzier tnx but i want to keep the changes inside the loop can u please do it

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.metal.deals,function(i,item){

        // alert("id:"+item.id+" color:"+item.color.id);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = { metal: { deals: [ { id: 1, color: { id: 608290 } } ] } };

$.each(metal.deals,function(index,item){

 $.each(item,function(itemIndex,value)
{
//process your sub items


});
});
```

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        $.each(data.response.deals, function(index, item)
        {
            //item is the object you have in the array
            //item.id ==> The id value in the object
            //item.color.id ==> The id value in the color object
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function like this:

```
function deepTraverse(obj, indent) {
    var str = "";
    for (var key in obj) {
        var newIndent = indent + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";     // <-- for formatting only
        str += newIndent + key + ": ";
        str += (typeof obj[key] != "object")
                ? obj[key] + "<br />"
                : "<br />" + deepTraverse(obj[key], newIndent);
        if (typeof obj[key] != "object") {
            alert(key + ": " + obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

See also this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/vvgKn/)**.